# Power-BI DATEDIFF from 2 different dimension tables, related to fact table

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff

This fact table is central. I'd like to create a measure with a DATEDIFF between the "StartVerkoopdatum" date and the "KAOOndertekend" date, related to this fact. Every fact line get's a value DATEDIFF(StartVerkoopdatum, KAOOndertekend, DAY).

The red lines are the connected fields. The blue arrows are the values I'd like to use in the datediff.

Is it possible to create a measure in the fact, that wil get this value?

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tmsO.png)

Comment: Everything looks good. Have you tried creating the measure with the code you've provided? Did you encounter a specific error?

Comment: It's a good idea to include tables with dummy data in markdown format with your questions. This makes it much easier to test and answer

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Answer (score 1):

Stack **strongly** recommends that you provide the sample data in [table format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow) and not picture.

Use the following measure

```
Measure =
DATEDIFF (
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( INT_Subproject[StartVerkoopdatum] ),
        //CROSSFILTER reverses the filter direction on-the-fly
        //to retrieve the MAX of dim by fact
        CROSSFILTER ( factINT[ProjID], INT_Subproject[ProjID], BOTH )
    ),
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( INT_Hoofdk[KAOOndertekend] ),
         //CROSSFILTER reverses the filter direction on-the-fly
        //to retrieve the MAX of dim by fact
        CROSSFILTER ( factINT[HoofID], INT_Hoofdk[HoofID], BOTH )
    ),
    DAY
)
```